# How can we search text in static pages in liferay

Tags: jsp, lucene, liferay, liferay-6

I've got some JSP pages in my portlet application. Now I want to search in these pages with Liferay. How can I index the contents?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "static pages"? HTML files that are embedded in a web application?

Comment: jsp pages with some static content.

Comment: Please always add information by editing your question. And define what you mean with "searching"? You mean you want to use the default search and let Liferay index the result of your JSP pages? Btw JSP pages are _dynamic_ content.

Comment: Is it possible that liferay index the jsp pages? Or any other solution for this?

Comment: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/implementing-search-and-indexing

Comment: Entities are not available. Jsp pages are containing just text data.

Comment: Your JSP pages are _entities_ in the means of _search objects_.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to scan and parse your JSP pages in your own implementation of an `Indexer` and create one `Document` per page. I would suggest that you switch to HTML files if the pages really just contain static text data. That will make it easier to parse them with something like JSOUP.

See "[Implementing Search and Indexing](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/implementing-search-and-indexing)" for a documentation.

On the other hand: I would convert the JSP pages to Webcontent articles. In that case you can simply add them to a page and the search index is updated automatically. And your customer can even change the content of the pages.